# Getting Shiny to update the ui and and run long calculation afterwards

Tags: r, reactive-programming, shiny-server, shiny

I have been trying to implement a simple interface to run R scripts on Shiny. I want my launching application to give some idea of what it is doing to the user, the simpler thing I can imagine is annoucing to the user some long calculation is going to start before it actually does, so far I couldn't find a way to impose the server to send the updates to the UI before the calculation begins, and the UI gets blocked until the end of the script. Can anyone see a simple way to correct this or do I have completly change the way I approach the problem ?

Thank you for any help

server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

Exec = reactiveValues(stateTxt = "Not started", state = 0)

output$execStatus = renderText(Exec$stateTxt)
runCalc = function() {
    setwd(root) 
    Exec$stateTxt = "Calculating..."
    source("calc.R")       
    Exec$stateTxt = "Finished"
}

observeEvent(input$runCalc, {runCalc()})
)
```

ui.R

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
      # Application title
  headerPanel("Long Calculation"),

  sidebarPanel(
    actionButton("runCalc", "Run Calculation")
    ),

  mainPanel(verbatimTextOutput("execStatus"))


))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% what you want to do, but you can use the `withProgress()` function to display a note to the user for long calculations:

```
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output) {
  runCalc = function() {
    withProgress(message = 'Please stand by...', value = 1, {
      Sys.sleep(3)
      output$execStatus <- renderText("Calculation finished")
      })
  }
  observeEvent(input$runCalc, {runCalc()})
  }

ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Long Calculation"), 
  sidebarPanel(
    actionButton("runCalc", "Run Calculation")
  ),  
  mainPanel(verbatimTextOutput("execStatus"))
)

shinyApp(server=server, ui=ui)
```

This way, you can also increment the progress bar and thus improve the ease of use:

```
  runCalc = function() {
    withProgress(message = 'Please stand by...', min=0, max=1, {
      Sys.sleep(1)
      incProgress(0.3)
      Sys.sleep(1)
      incProgress(0.3)
      Sys.sleep(1)
      incProgress(0.3)
      output$execStatus <- renderText("Calculation finished")
      })
  }
```